# Remove patterns of the form "{% ... %}" in a string

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing lines of a file for which I want to remove anything between "{%" and "%}", as these represent comments.

More specifically, a string such as

```
bla{% comment %} bli {% useless %}blu
```

should return

```
bla bli blu
```

I have tried with a regular expression, by removing everything that was matched by `{% .* %}`:

```
import re
s = 'bla{% comment %} bli {% useless %}blu'
regexp = '{% .* %}'
comments = re.findall(regexp, s)
for comment in comments:
    s = s.replace(comment, '')
print s
```

This gives `blablu` and erases `bli`. While I understand why it behaves like that, I don't know how to get `blabliblu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) and make you regex non-greedy adding `?`.

```
import re
s = 'bla{% comment %} bli {% useless %}blu'
regexp = '{% .*? %}'
s = re.sub(regexp, "", s)
print(s) # bla bli blu
```

Answer (score 6):

You need `.*?`. Your dot is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

```
regexp = '{% .*? %}'
```

When an operator is **greedy** is takes "as much as it can" and still result in a match, which means that it goes from the first `{%` to the last `%}`

```
bla{% comment %} bli {% useless %}blu
   ^ here        ...            ^ to here
```

When an operator is **lazy** is takes "as little as it can" and still result in a match, which means that it will go from the `{%` to the *next* `%}`.

Its also probably best to not explicitly add the spaces, as the pattern will not match comments without spaces:

```
regexp = '{%.*?%}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just explanation due to length it is as answer!

> **laziness alternative**( not using dot.)

```
{% [^\W]+ %}       
{% [^\W]* %}
{% [^\W]+? %}
{% [^\W]*? %}
{% [\w]+ %}
```

> **laziness variation**(not using asterisk)

```
{% .+? %}
```

Comment: This doesn't really _explain_ anything. It's little better than a code only answer. Except that it doesn't answer the question.